# Запятая на стыке союзов

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

"Имя твое" Петра Проскурина:

На середине реки, где уже лежала густая полоса солнца и под водой было светло, тихое течение замечалось по еле-еле шевелившимся верхушкам водяных трав, а когда она приближалась к затененному берегу, свет и под водой менялся, и там чудились глубокие провалы, заполненные тьмой и тайнами.

В одной рубахе, скинув полушубок и опорки, побежал он босиком по льду, и когда бежал, все потрескивал, мягко колыхался, подавался под ним лед, - упал, дополз на животе до полыньи и только посмотрел на черную дымящуюся воду, только завыл, зажмурился и пополз обратно.

Почему-то не ставится запятая перед "когда", как Розенталь рекомендует:

Надвигалась гроза, и, когда тучи заволокли все небо, стало темно, как в сумерки.

У Анны Ахматовой между присоединительным союзом "и" и подчин. "когда" запятая не ставится -  и это соответствует норме:

И когда друг друга проклинали
В страсти, раскаленной добела,
Оба мы еще не понимали,
Как земля для двух людей мала,

Чем это объяснить?

Comment: Впрочем у Розенталя есть такое:

Сборы затянулись, а когда все было готово к отъезду, ехать не имело уже смысла (после противительного союза а запятая в этих случаях, как правило, не ставится, так как ни изъятие, ни перестановка следующего за союзом придаточного предложения невозможны).

Правда, не пойму, почему перестановк невозожна. Разве нельзя так переставить предложения:

Сборы затянулись, а ехать не имело уже смысла, когда все было готово к отъезду.

Comment: В случае, связанном со стихотворением А.Ахматовой, по-моему, "и" - это не союз, а частица, поэтому запятая после и в этой ситуации не ставится. Впрочем, надо бы посмотреть предшествующую часть стиха.

Comment: Запятая обычно не ставится между присоединительным союзом (после точки) и союзом подчинительным, например: И кто вы такой, я знаю; А зачем это говорится, мне непонятно. Возможность постановки запятой после других присоединительных союзов связана с интонационно-смысловым выделением придаточного предложения, например: Однако, если вы так настаиваете на своем предложении, я готов его принять.

Comment: так что у Ахматовой другой случай - присоед. союз в начале предложения после точки. И пунктуация соответствует Розенталю. А у Проскурина //и когда бежал// "и" не после точки, сочин. союз. По-моему здесь нужна запятая: и, когда бежал. Можно ведь изъять придаточное или переставить.

Comment: Сборы затянулись, а ехать не имело уже смысла, когда все было готово к отъезду.- И какой получился смысл? Что противопоставлено? У автора противопоставлены не сказуемые главных предложений, а первое простое и сложноподчинённое.

Answer (score 3):

В одной рубахе, скинув полушубок и опорки, побежал он босиком по льду, и когда бежал, все потрескивал, мягко колыхался, подавался под ним лед... Постановка запятой связана с интонационно-смысловым выделением или невыделением  придаточного предложения. Союз И  относится по смыслу ко всему сложноподчинённому, а не только к главному предложению, значит, придаточное выделять не следует. Здесь "то" напрашивается.

...побежал он босиком по льду, и когда бежал, ..., подавался под ним лед... [= -],и
    /(когда), [= -]/.

Comment: А женщина все говорила и говорила о своих несчастьях, и, хотя слова ее были привычными, у Сабурова от них вдруг защемило сердце (Симонов) (при изъятии придаточного уступительного с союзом хотя предложно-местоименное сочетание от них становится неясным, но в структурном отношении такое изъятие возможно, поэтому запятая между сочинительным и подчинительным союзами в подобных случаях обычно ставится).

может, дело просто в предпоследнем слове "обычно"? И иногда запятая не ставится. А разницы по существу я все же не вижу.

Comment: Существенной нет,но автор хотел сказать то, что сказал, наше дело его понять, а не исправить: в чужой монастырь со своим уставом...Вы правильно заметили - обычно. Кто ставит, кто не ставит.Строгого регламента в таких предложениях нет.